# Internal log error in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Whenever I compile my package, Oracle SQL developer is showing this.

Any action to be taken from my side in scripting ? How can I avoid this ? Any serious issue in scripting?

Version-21.4.3.063
[image: Oracle SQLdeveloper]

Comment: Two things, posting pictures of Error Messages is mean. Also, are you noticing any actual loss of service in the tool and what are you doing when you see this message - what kind of scripts are you running?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I edited the package body and save it. It will be auto compiled on every save and giving me this log

Comment: and if you run said pl/sql program, do you see any loss of functionality/service?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith no loss in functionality